# Clarification (not solution) regarding K&R exercises

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

while going through the first chapter I found a question *to remove all comments from a code" - I really don't know what the author expects, whether I am supposed to use File handling (which in later chapters) or am I supposed to type in the entire file as an input?

Comment: The logic will be the same: 1) fetch a character 2) do I want this to be in the output? if so:output it.  3)goto1.   Concluding: you can do both, (you could even use macros for the get_chararacter and put_character parts)

Comment: @wildplasser I don't really care for the output or method - just the way to handle the input! :)

Comment: It appears from your question, the author expects you to do a *line-oriented* read (with either `fgets` or POSIX `getline` and remove from `/*....*/` (which can span multiple lines) and `//...` until the end of line. If nothing is left over after removing the comments, you can just not-output the line, otherwise you will output that part of the line not within the comment. (I could be wrong, but that's how I read it)

Comment: The *problem* with fgets() or getline() is that you *still* have to scan the sting character by character (or: use strstr(), which effectively does the same)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Of course there's also line-continuation using \ at the end of the line...

Comment: @Deduplicator -- ooh, good catch, that does throw another couple of *sticky-wickets* into the mix `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need file handling, you can use "getline" like in the later examples in chapter 1 to parse lines. Then if you want to use your code on a file you can pipe the file as input to the executable you have written.

You could also use "getchar" as in the "wc" example (line, word, and character counting example) given in Section 1.5.4. In that example program there is no file handling, but you can pipe a file the executable just as you would for the usual linux "wc" utility.

Comment: Can you provide some links to learn how to push input using pipe? Till now I was feeding input by using getchar() even for WC/WL programs.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus -- no, no, he is just saying you can provide input to your program on `stdin` by piping input to it, e.g. like `echo "1, 2, 3" | ./your_program` or redirecting a file to it, e.g. `./your_program <somefile`. That way, instead of having to open a `FILE *stream` with `fopen`, etc... you simply read from `stdin` which is available by default to your program.

Comment: BTW This is the kind of program that can use its own source as (test)input: `./your_program  <./your_program.c` ;-)